# change content in current page if previous page url with “-cn” ending in last 3 digits

Tags: jquery

I am making a site in both English and Chinese language, now I need to detect if previous page url with last 3 digits "-cn" ending (so will know it is chinese page) then change some content in current page(default is in English). Thank you.

code below, sorry I'm too new to JS

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
       var referrer =  document.referrer;
        if(referrer.indexOf("-cn")>-1) // previous url contains "-cn" ending
        {// change content
        $("#analytics").html('{module_contentholder, name="Upper Analytics-cn"}');
        $("#browser-alert").html('{module_contentholder, name="Box - Old Browser Message-cn"}');
        $("#header-a").html('{module_contentholder, name="Header - A-cn"}');
        $("#above-footer").html('{module_contentholder, name="Above Footer-cn"}');
        $("#Footer").html('{module_contentholder,name="Footer-cn"}');
        $("#Footer-Scripts").html('{module_contentholder, name="Footer - Scripts-cn"}');
        $("#Footer-Analytics").html("{module_contentholder,name='Footer - Analytics - Misc-cn'}");
        }
        else // Not contain "-cn" then do nothing
        {// do nothing
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect if previous page URL ends with "-cn", you should change your `if` statement to the following:

`if (document.referrer.slice(-3) == 'cn') // previous url **ENDS WITH** "-cn" ending`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.